# For each distinct value in a given column, count the null and non-null values in another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Suppose I have the following dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':['x','y','z','x','x','x','y','z','y','y'],
                'col2':[np.nan,'n1',np.nan,np.nan,'n3','n2','n5',np.nan,np.nan,np.nan]})
```

for each distinct element in `col1` I want to count how may null and non-null value are there in `col2` and summarise the result in a new dataframe. So far I used `df1 = df[df['col1']=='x']` and then

```
print(df1[df1['col2'].isna()].shape[0],
df1[df1['col2'].notna()].shape[0])
```

I was then manually changing the value in `df1` so that `df1 = df[df['col1']=='y']` and `df1 = df[df['col1']=='z']`. Yet my method is not efficient at all. The table I desire should look like the following:

```
  col1  value  no value
0    x      2         2
1    y      2         2
2    z      0         2
```

I have also tried `df.groupby('col1').col2.nunique()` yet that only gives me result when there is non-null value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us try [`crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) to create a frequency table where the index is the unique values in column `col1` and columns represent the corresponding `counts` of `non-nan` and `nan` values in `col2`:

```
out = pd.crosstab(df['col1'], df['col2'].isna())
out.columns = ['value', 'no value']
```

---

```
>>> out

      value  no value
col1                 
x         2         2
y         2         2
z         0         2
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`SeriesGroupBy.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.value_counts.html) with [`SeriesGroupBy.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.value_counts.html) for counts with reshape by [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html) and some data cleaning:

```
df = (df['col2'].isna()
                .groupby(df['col1'])
                .value_counts()
                .unstack(fill_value=0)
                .reset_index()
                .rename_axis(None, axis=1)
                .rename(columns={False:'value', True:'no value'}))
print (df)
  col1  value  no value
0    x      2         2
1    y      2         2
2    z      0         2
```